# Identify the type of probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem.

> Given a box with n cards, where each card is numbered from 1 to $n$, a card is taken out at random each time (without returning) until a card numbered 4 is taken out.
>
> Mark $X$ as the amount of cards we need to take out until 4 is reached.
>
> What is the probability distribution of X?

At first I thought it's a hypergeometric, as there are no returns. But Hypergeometric counts only the amount of $m$ special items.

I've come to the conclusion that:

$P\{X=N\}=\frac{1}{(n+1-N)!}$

But I can't relate that to any known distributions. (Such as geometric, Binomial, negative Binomial, etc..)

I would appreciate some insight on the matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your distribution formula is correct?

Comment: The way I read it, you should be getting a uniform distribution.  You are taking out cards without replacement, so we can as an analog just look at the probability that the $4$ is the $x$-th card in any permutation of the $n$ cards

Comment: I suspect that your attempted calculation of the distribution went something like "*If the $4$ occurs in the $N$'th position then there are $\frac{n!}{(n-N+1)!}$ ways in which the first $N$ cards can be pulled such that the $N$'th card was the four.  Take this and divide by $n!$ to find the probability.*"  This is incorrect because $n!$ counts the number of ways the **entire deck** was ordered, and your numerator did not account for how the rest of the cards were ordered after the $4$ (*even though we never needed to look at them and draw them*).  Further, there are $n-1$ not-4 cards, not $n$.

Comment: Correcting your attempt, you still need to multiply your numerator by the number of ways the remainder of the deck after the $4$ is ordered.  This can be done in $(n-N)!$ ways, and your first fraction was corrected to be $\frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-N+1)!}$, or rather $\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-N)!}$.  You can see how these will cancel out.  You are left with a probability of $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$ which simplifies to just $\dfrac{1}{n}$, irrespective of the choice of $N$... that is to say, this is just the uniform distribution.

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] tag, which has nothing to do with the geometric distribution. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when chosing tags.